# Refering elements of dataframe in R

Tags: r

i have following a data in csv file

```
1 - Landing Page
2 - Product Listing Page
4 - Shopping Bag
5 - Shipping Address
6 - Payment Selection
7 - Order Confirmation
Others
```

I am loading the data in a dataframe in R
`df1 <- read.csv("D:/data.csv", header=TRUE)`. The name of header is action.

I want to get the string in a single cell, but its not coming.
I have tried

```
df1[1]
df1[1,1]
df1[1][1]
df1[[1]][1]
df1[[1]]
df1$action[1]
```

But I am unable to extract the individual strings, so that i can compare them with other string using identical function

```
identical(df$Event_Action[1],df1[1,1])
```

Please suggest a way.

Comment: When you read in csvs, "always" use the as.is=TRUE option. This will read in character variables, which are usually what you want until graphing or modelling. `df1 <- read.csv("D:/data.csv", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a `factor` column, so convert it to `character` and then use `identical`

```
 identical(as.character(df$Event_Action[1]),as.character(df1[1,1]))
```